# I am working on a GUI which has several pages (I used different classes to show different pages). The problem I am facing is with navigation

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to navigate to different pages of the GUI and on some pages, I need a timer if the timer expires then it will automatically redirect the user to `Startpage`. or if the user navigate then also timer will stop and the user will land on another page. The problem is that the timer of other pages is running in background and randomly takes user to start page. I am not able to figure out how to solve this
The code I developed is as follows:

```py
import os
from itertools import cycle
import PIL.ImageTk, PIL.Image
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


LARGEFONT = ("Roboto", 35)

directory = r"C:\Users\mojave\tkinter\bg_images"
images = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
    images.append(os.path.join(directory,filename))
  else:
    continue

print(images)
#images = ["bg1.jpg", "bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg"]
photos = cycle(PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=image) for image in images)


class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)

        self.geometry('%dx%d' % (1366, 768))
        

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0,column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.event_generate("<<ShowFrame>>")
        
    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]
     # 1 second(s)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.photo = PhotoImage(file = r"recycle_icon.png")
        self.photoimage = self.photo.subsample(20,20)
        btnFont = font.Font(family='Roboto',size=32,weight='bold')
        #app.geometry('%dx%d' % (1366, 768))

        global displayCanvas 
        displayCanvas = ttk.Label(self)
        displayCanvas.place(x=0,y=0)

        self.after(10,lambda: slideShow())

        label = ttk.Label(self,text="StartPage", font=LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))

        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "page 2",
        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))

        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 10,pady = 10)

        start_btn = tk.Button(self,text="\nStart Recycle",height=650, width=300,image=self.photoimage, 
        compound= TOP, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1), activebackground="green", background="red", foreground="white", bd=5)
        start_btn['font'] = btnFont
        #start_btn.pack(side=TOP)
        start_btn.place(x=1010,y=60)
        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.on_show_frame)
    def on_show_frame(self,event):
        print("start page is shown..")


class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        #label = ttk.Label(self, text = "Page 1", font = LARGEFONT)
        #label.grid(row = 0,column = 4,padx = 10,pady = 10)
        lang_btnFont = font.Font(family='Roboto',size=32,weight='bold')
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file = r"recycle_icon.png")
        self.photoimage = self.photo.subsample(20,20)
        
        self.img1 = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\\Users\\mojave\\tkinter\\bg_image.jpg')
        displayCanvas1 = ttk.Label(self)
        displayCanvas1.config(image=self.img1)
        displayCanvas1.place(x=0,y=0)

        lang_btn = tk.Button(self,text="English",height=300, 
        width=300,image=self.photoimage,compound=TOP, command= lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2), 
        activebackground= "green",background="red",foreground="white")
        lang_btn['font'] = lang_btnFont
        lang_btn.place(x=1010,y=60)

        lang_btn2 = tk.Button(self,text="हिन्दी",height=300, width=300,image=self.photoimage,compound=TOP, 
        command= lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2), activebackground= 
        "green",background="red",foreground="white")
        lang_btn2['font'] = lang_btnFont
        lang_btn2.place(x=1010,y=400)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="StartPage",image=self.photoimage,command= lambda : 
        controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1,padx = 10,pady = 10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self,text = "Page 2", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 10,pady = 10)

        self.timer_label1 = tk.Label(self,font = LARGEFONT, text="10s")
        self.timer_label1.place(x=2,y=200)

        self.timer_thread = Thread(target = self.on_show_frame)
        self.timer_thread.start()
        self.after(100,self.on_show_frame)

        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.on_show_frame)
    
    def on_show_frame(self,event=None):
        print("page1 is shown..")
        self.start = 10
        self.temp = self.start
        while self.temp >= 0:
            self.timer_label1.config(text = str(self.temp)+ "s")
            self.timer_label1.update()

            if self.temp == 0:
                self.timer_thread._is_running = False
                show_frame_g(StartPage)
                break
            self.temp -=1
            sleep(1)


class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self,text = "Page 2", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0,column = 4,padx=10,pady = 10)

        self.img1 = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\\Users\\mojave\\tkinter\\bg_image2.jpg')
        displayCanvas1 = ttk.Label(self)
        displayCanvas1.config(image=self.img1)
        displayCanvas1.place(x=0,y=0)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Page 1",command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid(row = 1,column = 1, padx = 10,pady = 10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self,text="Start Page", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 10, pady = 10)

       

       
       
        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.on_show_frame)
    def on_show_frame(self,event):
        print("page2 is shown..")
        #self.after(10000,lambda : show_frame_g(StartPage))


app = tkinterApp()

show_frame_g = app.show_frame

#def time_update():
#    onTime_page2 =+ 1



def slideShow():
    img = next(photos)
       
    displayCanvas.config(image=img)
    app.after(1000,slideShow) #after 1s

app.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the timer of other pages is running in background and randomly takes user to start page. I am not able to figure out how to solve this

Comment: You shouldn't use `ImageTk.PhotoImage` before you create your `tk.Tk()` window.

Comment: @TheLizzard I am not facing the problem with images. I am concerned about the timer implementation. Thanks a lot for replying

Comment: Please remove all of the unnecessary code. We don't want to debug 200+ lines of code.

Comment: @MohitSharma dude he tries helping You and You turn him down, there is obviously a reason why he said You shouldn't do, so maybe don't. so about Your problem. as far as I understand You want a timer that when ends sets focus to Startpage and while user is in other pages timer doesn't count? correct. so basically the only time the timer counts is when focus is on none of the pages?

Comment: also Your imports are a bit messed up and I suggest using `f strings`

Comment: @TheLizzard sorry I added the whole code so anyone can properly understand what I'm doing. look at the `show_frame` function in tinkerApp class, it generates an event. This generated event is listened by other page classes and binds it to the `on_show_frame` function . and on_show_frame function sets the frame to StartPage if timer is at 0 but here is the problem , suppose I navigate to other page when timer was at 6 but while on other page the function is still running in the background and when it reaches 0 it takes me to StartPage

Comment: @Matiiss Yes I want a timer that runs on every page except `StartPage` and when on any page the timer expires it sets focus on `StartPage` and also if user navigates to other page the timer of previous page stops/resets and only timer of current page runs, here is the problem I'm facing when user navigates to other page the timer of previous is not killed. It is running in background and when it expires it is taking me to `StartPage`

Comment: add an event bind, that whenever the window is out of focus call the stop timer function, sth like: `self.bind('<FocusOut>', stop_timer)` oh, and bind it also to: `self.bind('<FocusIn>', start_timer)`, this should be applied to all the windows  except maybe the StartPage or sth like that

Comment: Instead of including the entirety of your program, it would be helpful if you could create a minimal, reproducible example. [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information